# @BeforeTest beforeTest("WIN8", "firefox", "http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub") java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: remoteurl

Tags: xml, testng, virtualbox, selenium-grid

I am trying to run Selenium Grid by registering a node from VirtualBox. Whenever I try to execute `testng.xml` to run tests in parallel, I get the following error:FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest  how to resolve this.
I made sure all the necessary jar files are added. Selenium hub is running and node is also been registered to the hub.

```
 package com.example.selenium;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

    public class ParllelTest {
//RemoteWebDriverInstance
        static RemoteWebDriver driver;
  //Checking the type of browser and platform registered   

      @BeforeTest (alwaysRun=true)
      @Parameters({"platform","browserName","remoteurl"})
      public void beforeTest(String platform,String browserName,String remoteurl) throws MalformedURLException {

         DesiredCapabilities cap = null;


          if(browserName.equals("firefox")) {

              cap=new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
           cap.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
          cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
          }

          else if(browserName.equals("chrome"))
          {
              cap=new DesiredCapabilities().chrome();
              cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
              cap.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
          }


          driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("remoteurl"),cap);
      }
//navigating to particular page
      @Test
      public void googlesearch() 
      {


          driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
          driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.findElement(By.id("click")).click();
      }
    }
```

Iam pasting corresponding xml file from where iam trying to run the test in parallel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests" >
<test verbose="3" name="Vista">
<paramaters>
   <parameter name="platform" value="VISTA"/>
   <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
   <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://10.x.x.x:5557/wd/hub"/>
</paramaters>
<classes>
    <class name="com.example.selenium.ParllelTest">
     <method>
        <include name="googlesearch"/>
      </method>   
    </class>
</classes>
</test>
<test verbose="3" name="ubuntu">
 <paramaters>
   <parameter name="platform" value="WIN8"/>
   <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
   <parameter name="remoteurl" value="http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub"/>
</paramaters>
<classes>
    <class name="com.example.selenium.ParllelTest">
       <method>
        <include name="googlesearch"/>
      </method>   
     </class>
</classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

Comment: What do you have in method annotated with @BeforeTest.

Comment: Iam pasting the code in my question

Comment: Please dont downvote  iam an absolute beginner to selenium.Iam really stuck here from long time need help.

Comment: Downvotes are a measure of the usefulness of your question to the community, not of the amount of pity you are worth.  I'm not a downvoter, but I suggest you review the instructions for how to create a [mcve] and then maybe [edit] your question to focus it.

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: remoteurl

```
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("remoteurl"),cap);
```

Looking at the exception and this line, looks like your parameter remoteurl is not getting decoded to its value i.e. http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub. Rather it is getting passed as "remoteurl" string which obviously can not be parsed into url.

Just for confirming this, try to put the value of remoteurl in the above line of code as :

```
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub"), cap)
```

It will surely work, then it is a question why remoteurl is being passed as string instead of variable, if the above line works, then try passing remoteurl without quotes as below :

```
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteurl), cap)
```

Although I am not 100% sure about the remoteurl or "remoteurl" but lets try. for the first point I am 100% sure that new URL is receiving "remoteurl" instead of "http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub".

Comment: Thank you.But using "http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub" can execute on single machine but i want to execute tests in parallel on both machines with IP:"http://10.x.x.x:4467/wd/hub"   and "http://10.x.x.x:5557/wd/hub"